# How to add vertical header in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I am new in Pantaho PRPT, and want to create PDF with vertical headers left side and data on right side like below example. I have created PDF with header top aligned similar to table header and table data but unable to create table with below structure:

By vertical header I mean that the table has the header tag on the left side (generally)

Header 1 data data data

Header 2 data data data

Header 3 data data data